# Wedge product and linear independence

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tensors

The following question was from my assignment on smooth manifolds and I am struck on this problem

> Let V be a n-dimensional vector space and $w_1,...,w_k \in A^{1} (V)$. Show that {$w_1,...,w_k$} are linearly independent iff $w_1 \bigwedge w_2 \bigwedge ... \bigwedge w_k \neq 0$ .

Attempt: I will prove the contrapositive. Let  {$w_1,...,w_k$} is Linearly dependent => $c_1 w_1 +...+c_k w_k =0$ for some $c_i's \in V$
WLOG, let $c_1$ be non -zero.  Then $w_1 = - \frac{(c_2 w_2 +...+ c_k w_k)} {c_1}$ and now using the property that $x\bigwedge x =0$, I get that the wedge product of $w_i's$ is 0.

Conversely, let the wedge product is 0. But, in this case I am not sure which result I should use to prove linear dependence.

Can you please help me with the proof? Thanks!

Comment: If they're independent, you can extend to a basis, then their wedge is non-zero

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks!